# Show that if $G$ is simple a graph with $n$ vertices and the number of edges $m>\binom{n-1}{2}$, then $G$ is connected.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I'm trying to pick up a little graph theory out of Bondy and Murty's *Graph Theory* as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/what-are-good-books-to-learn-graph-theory).

Problem 1.1.12 has given me a little hitch.

> Let $G$ be a simple graph of order $n$ and size $m$. (So there are $n$ vertices and $m$ edges). If $m>\binom{n-1}{2}$, then $G$ is connected.

I'm following a hint in an appendix which says if $G$ is not connected, we can partition the vertices into parts $(X,Y)$ such that no edge joins a vertex in $X$ to a vertex in $Y$. What is the largest number of edges in $G$ if $|X|=r$ and $|Y|=n-r$?

I suppose the graphs on $X$ and $Y$ are then complete graphs, for a total of $\binom{r}{2}+\binom{n-r}{2}$ edges. Simplifying, this is $\frac{2r^2+n^2-2rn-n}{2}$, so I'm trying to show
$$
\frac{2r^2+n^2-2rn-n}{2}\leq\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}
$$
to get the contrapositive.

The above is equivalent, if my algebra is correct, to showing $r\geq\frac{n-1}{n-r}$ for any $0\lt r\lt n$. This seems reasonable, but I can't quite show it. How would I do so? 
Thanks.

I'd also be happy to see a solution that doesn't necessarily make use of the hint.

Comment: I think the title of your question would've been better as "Is a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|E| > \binom{|V|-1}2$ connected?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
r &\ge \frac{n-1}{n-r}\\
rn-r^2 &\ge n-1\\
rn-r^2-n+1 &\ge 0\\
(r-1)n-(r-1)(r+1) &\ge 0\\
(r-1)(n-r-1) &\ge 0
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Quick and clean, thank you.