# How to determine if a simple graph of $7$ vertices where the degree of each vertex is at least $3$ is connected?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

> How to determine if a simple graph of $7$ vertices where the degree of each vertex is at least $3$ is connected?

According to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34601/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-simplicity-and-connectedness-in-graphs?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) we need to check that $|E|>{7-1\choose 2}=15$. If the degree of each vertex is at least $3$ then $\sum_{v\in V}deg(v)=21$. But $\sum_{v\in V}deg(v)$ cannot be odd so there must be at least one vertex with degree $4$ therefore $\sum_{v\in V}deg(v)=22$ at least. In such case $|E|=11$.

We see that $|E|<{7-1\choose 2}$ therefore the graph cannot be connected.

But on the other hand because the degree of one of the vertices is $4$ then there's a subgraph which has $5$ vertices. Suppose the other $2$ vertices are not connected but this cannot be because the degree of each vertex is at least $3$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the first part of the answer you link to gives only a _sufficient_ condition for being connected, not a _necessary_ one (despite the _question_ there asking for both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems easier to me just to say: If every vertex has at least 3 neighbors, then a connected component will have at least 4 vertices in it.
7 vertices is therefore not enough to have two connected components.