# Proving a graph must be connected

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges such that $e>\binom{n-1}{2}$. Then $G$ must be connected. As usual, hints would be greatly appreciated. If it where$\binom{n}{2}$ then wouldn't everything be adjacent to itself? I'll try to answer the question myself at the end if I'm able to.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34212/for-a-graph-g-if-m-binomn-12-then-g-is-connected?rq=1

Comment: Yep. My bad. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ is disconnected, the [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph) of $G$ contains a [complete bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph) $K_{m,n-m}$ subgraph for some $m \in \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ (the vertices of one component of $G$ forms one part, the remaining vertices are in the other part).  Thus, there are at least $m(n-m)$ non-edges in $G$.

Since $K_{m,n-m}$ has $m(n-m)$ edges, the number of edges in $G$ is at most
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{2}-m(n-m) &= \binom{n-1}{2}+n-1-m(n-m) \\
 &\leq \binom{n-1}{2}
\end{align*}
since the parabola $f_n(m):=n-1-m(n-m)\leq 0$ for all $m \in \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$.  (This can be proved by showing that $1$ and $n-1$ are roots of $f_n(m)-1$ and showing $f_n(m)-1<0$ when $1<m<n-1$.)

Hence a disconnected graph has at most $\binom{n-1}{2}$ edges.