# Free Graph Theory Resources

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, online-resources

What freely available graph theory resources are there on the web? In particular, I am interested in books and lecture notes containing topics such as trees, connectivity, planar graphs, the probabilistic method ect., though no resources is expected to be comprehensive.

Note that I have searched MathOnline, which yielded the book Graph Theory by Reinhard Diestel. This resources seems to be good, but I prefer to have multiple resources when studying a topic.

Note: I am aware of the many questions on this site regarding book suggestions for particular topics. While this question is related, I am only interested in freely available resources, as I am a broke college student.

Comment: I have written these introductory notes together with a PhD-student: http://01227graphtheory.wordpress.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/what-are-good-books-to-learn-graph-theory

Comment: @lhf My question differs from that one because I looking for free books and lecture notes on graph theory. Thank you for linking it though, because it has 1 resource I had not seen before.

Comment: @froggie, he already mentioned in the question, that he know Diestel's book, and is looking for additional resources.

Comment: These are great http://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/ii/Graph_Theory.pdf

Comment: [Graph Theory with Applications](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~jabondy/books/gtwa/gtwa.html) by Bondy and Murthy is a classic.

Comment: Perhaps you could collect all the comments into an answer.

Comment: @lhf I will do so.

Comment: Does your university have Springerlink?  If so, you can download lots of books for free.  Just search for graph theory and then after the results come up, select Books (and maybe Lecture Notes) in content type.  I know Bondy and Murty's graduate text is available.

A book that is available online for free, that does not fit your specifications exactly, would be Spectra of Graphs by Haemers and Brouwer.  It's a spectral graph theory book.

Comment: I'd also like to add one:  For a well-written introduction to the probabilistic method, try the notes by Matousek and Vondrak, they can be found on the [Matousek's home page](http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/)

Comment: @JohnEngbers I have added them. Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note: I will update this list as addition resources come to my attention.

Lecture Notes:

- [Lecture Notes on Geometric Graph Theory by Janos Pach]
  [ps](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&ved=0CFcQFjAEOAo&url=http://dcg.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/dcg/files/users/191651/public/lecture%2520notes.ps&ei=NFi7T4K-NcaQswaQv7z9Bw&usg=AFQjCNGS1-W5tkSNRSria89RBZa1hmPyeQ&sig2=tspcycLYlbjol9uHdWUrqg)
- [Princeton Lecture Notes]
  http://web.math.princeton.edu/math_alive/5/Notes1.pdf
  http://web.math.princeton.edu/math_alive/5/Notes2.pdf
- [PSU Lecture Notes by Christopher Griffin]
  http://www.personal.psu.edu/cxg286/Math485.pdf
- [TU Denmark Lecture Notes by Hjalte Wedel Vildhøj and David Kofoed Wind]
  http://www.student.dtu.dk/~s082951/01227/01227-GraphTheory.pdf
- [University of Turku Lecture Notes by Tero Harju]
  http://users.utu.fi/harju/graphtheory/graphtheory.pdf
- [Probabilistic Method by Matousek and Vondrak]
  http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/lectnotes.html
- [Lectures Notes for Spectral Graph Theory by Steve Butler]
  http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbutler/spectral/
- [Lecture Notes on Graph Coloring by Frédéric Havet]
  http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Frederic.Havet/Cours/coloration.pdf

Books:

- [Graph Theory with Applications by J.A. Bondy and U.S.R. Murty]
  http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~jabondy/books/gtwa/gtwa.html
- [Graph Theory by Reinhard Diestel]
  http://www.esi2.us.es/~mbilbao/pdffiles/DiestelGT.pdf
- [Combinatorics of Subsets and Graphs by Fan Chung]
  http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/teach/262/notes/steve/262_book.pdf

Comment: '+1' Any updates?

Answer (score 4):

https://openknol.wikidot.com

Links to Lecture notes, monographs, survey papers in combinatorics, graph theory and related fields of mathematics and computer science.

Answer (score 1):

Vadim Lozin's Lecture Notes:

http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgax/notes.pdf