# Introductory Level Books for Graph Theory

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Can anybody please suggest some good  introductory level text books on Graph Theory ?

Preferably those which don't really require a great pre-requisite background on discrete mathematics, but rather serve to build such a background throughout the book.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/what-are-good-books-to-learn-graph-theory

Comment: There is a question: [What are good books to learn graph theory?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/what-are-good-books-to-learn-graph-theory) (Mentioned in gev's comment, too.)
But the OP there asks for more advanced books: *directed towards a student who has taken most the standard undergraduate courses*.

Answer (score 1):

Bela Bollabas's two books on graph theory are quite good addition to the lists given above.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 'Introduction to Graph Theory' by Douglas B. West.I love this book.Excellent book content.Great for beginners.