# In Graph to tree: name of operation where edges removed and vertex/edge additions?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, connectedness, trees, st-connectivity

[image]
The graph has tree paths *IN-1-OUT, IN-2-OUT* and *IN-3&4-OUT* between IN and OUT in the left. I want to make each path to a branch like the right.

[image]

*What is the name of this operation or the name of this procedure to make a graph into a tree?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not tree unless changes such as changing the OUT vertices or removing paths**

This picture below does not represent a tree because

> [*"a tree is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by **exactly one path**."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory))

where you have many paths between IN vertex and OUT vertex. You could call different OUT vertices with OUT1, OUT2 and OUT3 -- similarly for paths IN-3-OUT and IN-4-OUT so each parallelization increases the number of OUT vertices by one.

[image]

**Operations to make the graph to tree**

The name of the operations contain insertion of vertices and removal/insertion of edges as written in the picture. Other way to see this is to consider graph theory in terms of linear algebra. So

1. the path matrix $P_{in}$ where $in$ is the root is {{1, out}, {2,out}, {3,out}, {4,out}} while the reduced path matrx $P_{in}^{-1}$ is {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}} with the last out-edge removed.
2. Path matrix $P_n$ representation for graph $G$ where $n$ is a root vertex. The $j$th column is a path such that the entry is 1 if the edge in the path and 0 otherwise. (Page 17 of Graphs And Matrices by Babat 2nd ed)
3. [Textbook on Graph Theory using Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527842/textbook-on-graph-theory-using-linear-algebra)