# Nice survey paper to learn features of graph structure

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, book-recommendation

I'm learning features of graph structure such as centrality, degree, distance, clustering coefficient, k-core, the number of common neighbors etc.

Please let me know nice survey papers (or books maybe) that list up those features as much as possible.

I know there are a lot of [nice books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/what-are-good-books-to-learn-graph-theory?rq=1) to learn graph theory. But, what I'm looking for is not for student or beginner. A material specialized for listing up features of graph mining or graph link prediction.

Particularly, I'm interested in features that represent relationship between two nodes. While the most naive feature is shortest distance, I'd like to know many features representing the relationship of two nodes.