# Good books on graph theory for self-study?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request

Recently I plan to study graph theory. I tried to read the book [A Course in Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521006015), yet I found the text hard to follow and problems *too difficult*. I'm just midway in chapter 2 and I already found several problems that I can't solve even after reading the hint and thinking for hours. (Is it just me or is it that the problems in this book are indeed really hard? And should I pursue reading this book?) So I want another book that (hopefully) satisfies the following:

1. Comprehensive.
2. Has good problems with *detailed* hints (compared to the book above).

Comment: Don't know if it will be useful or not, anyways, see: [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-books-for-self-studying-graph-theory), [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12161/what-are-some-good-beginner-graph-theory-texts#) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/what-are-good-books-to-learn-graph-theory).

Comment: The undergraduate book you linked to (a favorite of mine) is indeed about Combinatorics rather than just graph theory, an important subset.  Some suggestions may be found by following links in this related SciComp.SE Question, [What is a good introduction to graph theory / algorithm](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/what-is-a-good-introduction-to-graph-theory-algorithm)?  It certainly seems a *comprehensive* study of graph theory is beyond your current grasp.

Answer (score 0):

[Graph Theory](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783662536216) by Reinhard Diestel.

Electronic free edition is also available [here](http://www.esi2.us.es/~mbilbao/pdffiles/DiestelGT.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Douglas B.  West's book called **Introduction to Graph Theory** is a good book for self study.

You can find it here [west graph theory](http://home.ku.edu.tr/mudogan/public_html/Introduction%20to%20Graph%20Theory%202E%20-%20West.pdf).