# Books recommendation for combinatorics - From beginner to research

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Particularly I am interested in combinatorics, graph theory and algebra . In fact , my university did offer a lot of algebra courses so I am not worry about that . BUT my university seldom offer combinatorics and graph theory courses ( the only one was just discrete mathematics ) . I love combinatorics and graph theory and would like to do research in it .

My question is , is there a recommended book list for combinatorics and graph theory  from beginner level until be able to do research . It would be helpful for others who like combinatorics and graph theory too . If possible , a list by difficulty from beginner , intermediate , advanced and research level is recommended .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are links to other sites where people have asked this question:

https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-books-about-combinatorics

[Good Book On Combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/good-book-on-combinatorics)

[What are good books to learn graph theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/what-are-good-books-to-learn-graph-theory)

Only thing I would add is that Vol. 2 of Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics is also a great read. Particularly enjoyed that section on Catalan numbers.

Comment: These posts did have recommendation on books , but it does not list out the difficulties , which is hard for arrangement .

Answer (score 1):

Harris' Combinatorics and Graph Theory is a good beginner-intermediate book. In my own dissertation research, Combinatorial Optimization by Papadimitriou and Steiglitz took me to the Advanced to Research level, with papers supplying my own specified research needs.

Comment: So you meant by studying these two books and research papers , it is enough for me to start a research in combinatorics ?

Comment: You may or may not need more than these two books; I just wanted to offer two suggestions for you to help you get started. You (and if applicable, your advisor) will know whether your studies are sufficient to begin research, or whether you need more material than that contained in the two books I listed.