# A good book to learn graph algorithms

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

Can someone please tell a good reference to study algorithms in graph theory?

I've studied sufficient graph theory in discrete mathematics and data structures courses, which included topics like colouring, matching, planarity, BFS, DFS and Dijkstra's algorithm. But I'm unable to solve coding questions at all on competitive coding sites like codechef.

So, can someone please tell me a good book OR video tutorials online for the same? Thanks!

Comment: Check out "The Art of Computer Programming" by Donald E. Knuth or "The Stanford GraphBase: A Platform for Combinatorial Computing" by Donald E. Knuth

Comment: @Moritz Sure. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Take a look at Skiena's "The Algorithm Design Manual", Springer, 2008.

Comment: duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27480